# Não consigo visualizar os elementos de uma linha da tabela

Tags: php, sql

Estou tentando visualizar elementos de uma linha de uma tabela minha, só que separadamente. E não venho obtendo êxito.

Segue o código:

```
<?php

require_once("conexao.php");

$id = $_POST['idlicita'];

$query = "select * from licitacao where idlicita = $id";

$resultado = mysqli_query($conexao,$query);
$visu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado);

echo $visu["objeto"];
```

Trecho do formulário onde é passado a `ID` correspondente ao item que quero visualizar:

```
<form action="visualiza.php" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="idlicita" value="<?$licitacao['idlicita']?>">
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Visualizar</button>
</form>
```

EDIT:

Erro que está dando:

> Warning: mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result,
>   boolean given in C:\xampp\htdocs\painelnovo\pages\visualiza.php on
>   line 10

Comment: Para ler uma linha apenas não precisa do `while`, e apenas a instrução que está lá :`$visu = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado)`. No banco de dados para essa tabela `licitacao` tem um campo `objeto` ? E quando diz "E não venho obtendo êxito" acontece o quê ? Dá erro ? Se sim acrescente o erro à pergunta

Comment: Editei, tirei o while e coloquei somente uma linha

Comment: O `$_POST` não tem o campo `idlicita`. Confirme o que recebe do formulário com `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: não entendi o que você quis dizer

Comment: `<?$licitacao['idlicita']?>` falta um `=` e devia ser `<?=$licitacao['idlicita']?>`

Comment: Realmente era isso. Muito obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Tal como o @Isac disse, problema é que você tem um erro no código, falta-lhe o `=` em `<?$licitacao['idlicita']?>`. Por causa disso, ele está a enviar a variável em vazio e não consegue ir buscar.